# WordPress separate php file

Tags: php, wordpress

I created a new page in my admin panel. 
On this page, for example function `is_admin()` works fine.

```
if ( ! is_admin() ) {
     echo "You are viewing the theme";
} else {
     echo "You are viewing the WordPress Administration Panels";
}
```

From this page i send post data to xxx.php file.
And! In this xxx.php file functions such as is_admin doens't work.
How can i let wordpress to understand, that this xxx.php file is the part of him? So i can use functions on this page? 
I am using 
`"include wp-load.php"`
but it doesn't help me.

Comment: can you be more clear plz ? and give us a more complete code.

Answer (score 0):

You can add him in the theme folder & include in functions.php:

```
// functions.php of your current theme
    include __DIR__.'/custom.php';
```

Comment: Юлия, не помогло. 
Я в функциях добавил инклуд и кинул мой php файл в папку с темой и всё равно не работает.

Comment: /wp-content/themes/my-theme/custom.php - так да?
И в файле functions.php в конце   include __DIR__.'/custom.php';

выведите в custom.php: echo 'Test custom';
сверху должен вывестись текст

Comment: Да. Именно так и сделал

Comment: простите за вопрос: в админке тема какая активна?
если Seventeen, то пробуйте другую. В этой теме почему-то всегда проблемы.
Попробуйте Htm5blank

Comment: Я использую wp-advocate

Comment: Юлия, я попробую Вам объяснить, что у меня происходит. 
Я в админку вывел страницу, где вывожу форму с данными. И пишу action="xxx.php". На странице с админкой он проверяет is_admin(), а вот в файле xxx.php он не проверяет. Пишет, что я не админ. Я думаю, что вордпрес не понимает, что тут нужно вывести сессию или данные о том, что тут используется тоже данные логина и тд.

Comment: а фрагмент кода можно?
А то вот этого мало 
И пишу action="xxx.php".

Comment: Я думаю так

<form method="post">
<input type="hidden"  name="my_save_settings" >
.............

</form>


custom.php

if ( isset( $_POST['my_save_settings'] ) ){
что то делаем сохраняем и т.д.
}

Answer (score 0):

I just checked the source code on Github.

`function is_admin()` appears in this file https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/6fda2e67b0fe3872cbf5f82b58b98f2a4c96d8f8/wp-includes/load.php#L710-L717

So, `require_once 'wp-includes/load.php;` should sort you out.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you're sending POST data (request, i assume) to another php file makes me think that it's a completely different HTTP request, therefore you won't be able to use wp functions in the target php file, unless you include `wp-load.ph` in that file.

See this: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/69184/how-to-load-wordpress-on-non-wp-page

Answer (score 0):

```
add_action('admin_menu', function(){
  add_menu_page( 'Subscribe', 'Subscribe', 'manage_options', 'subsc-options', 'sub_setting', '', 4 ); 
} );


add_action( 'current_screen', function( $current_screen ){  // hook is admin panel only

  if ( stripos($current_screen->base, 'subsc-options')==true  ) {
      include __DIR__.'/custom.php';

  }

});



<form method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="my_save_settings" >
  ..............

</form>

/*********  CUSTOM.PHP **************/

if ( isset($_POST['my_save_settings']) ) {
  // save form fields
}
```

Comment: То есть add_action пишу в functions.php?